# How To Save a password in Click once application where no one can read it

Tags: c#, clickonce

Is there a way to save a password after installing click once application on the user's computer where no one can read it. C#

If I save a password whether inside the codes, or in the config file. Anyone can open the code and read it. There is must be a way where I can save the password in the registry or somewhere where no one can read it. I mean Microsoft who I love dearly, did a poor job on protecting the application from being exposed.

Comment: Are you using .Net?

Comment: What do you _really_ mean by "where no one can read it"? If taken literally, that's impossible.

Comment: I take it you mean encrypt it, as if it can't be read, then even that application would not be able to read it.  But then of course it is a matter of how you secure the encryption keys.

Comment: Encryption requires a key, if i save the key inside the application, they can read it and decrypt it?

Answer (score 0):

[Secure ClickOnce applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/securing-clickonce-applications?view=vs-2022#aspnet-form-based-authentication) (learn.microsoft.com)

> **ASP.NET form-based authentication**

> If you want to control which deployments each user can access, you should not enable anonymous access to ClickOnce applications deployed on a Web server. Rather, you would enable users access to the deployments you have installed based on a user's identity using Windows authentication.

> ClickOnce does not support ASP.NET forms-based authentication because it uses persistent cookies; these present a security risk because they reside in the Internet Explorer cache and can be hacked. Therefore, if you are deploying ClickOnce applications, any authentication scenario besides Windows authentication is unsupported.

Comment: I mean when Microsoft created ClickOnce application, they didn't think about security at all? I just i can't believe i can't hide or encrypt a string somewhere without being it exposed. I use the Simple3Des, which i love. But I can't save the private key anywhere where it will be secure.

Comment: Query-string arguments are the only way to pass arguments to a ClickOnce application at startup. (Is it safe to pass private key by using Query-String)